# Select all divs in the first row in a dynamic grid

Tags: css, html, sass, grid

I am using a grid with 12 columns. I want to give every div a margin-top:20px except the divs in the first row. But I have trouble to find out which divs are in the first row because its undefined.  The first row can contain 1 to 12 divs.

I am using sass and have tried the following solution but this only works with divs with same width. The first example wouldn't work because the second div doesn't get a margin.

```
// max. 12 rows. 
@for $colWidth from 1 through 12 {          
    // example: 3 divs in a row (colWidth = 4), 12/4+1 = 4.
    // Set margin from the fourth element to the last element.
    $number: (12/$colWidth) + 1;

    // set margin only for banner-component
    div.col-xs-#{$colWidth}:nth-child(n+#{$number}) section.banner-component {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    div.col-sm-#{$colWidth}:nth-child(n+#{$number}) section.banner-component {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

Ohter css selectors didn't work either. first-child, nth-child.
Any idea how I can select the divs in the first row?

Here are some examples:

Example 1: First row contains 1 div (col-lg-12)

```
<div> class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
```

Example 2: First row contains 2 divs (col-lg-6)

```
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
```

Example 3: First row contains 3 divs (col-lg-4)

```
<div> class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
```

Example 4: First row contains 3 divs (col-lg-4, col-lg-6, col-lg-2)

```
<div> class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-4 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
<div> class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <section class="banner-component"></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using pure CSS. Here's some alternative using jQuery. First, give some specific class/id to the grid container(the direct parent of the cols).

**Add a class on the css**

```
.with-top-margin{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var divs = $("#dynamic-cols-container > div");
var counter = 0;

for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
  var div = divs.get(i);
  if(counter < 12)
    $(div).addClass("with-top-margin");

  var divWidth = parseInt($(div).attr("class").split("col-lg-")[1].split(" ")[0]);
  counter += divWidth;
}
```

Hope this helps. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swy7e1t3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of having all your col divs in a wrapping container*

*only needed if the last row should align with bottom.

```
<div class="grid"> 
... any number of col divs 
</div>
```

Then you could do:

```
// add top margin to all col divs and use translate to move them
// up by the same amount (making first row align with top)
[class*="col-"]{ margin-top: 20px; transform: translateY(-20px); }

// in case you want the last row to align with the bottom 
// use a negative bottom margin on your container 
.grid { overflow: auto; margin-bottom: -20px; }
```

With wrapper:
[image]

Without wrapper:
[image]

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Both variants worked for me. I choosed the JQuery version and converted it to JSP.